# getting errors while creating MySQL function

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> creating a function but it gives error [database table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRvs7.png)

```
create function getAvg(id1 in number ,id2 in number) returns number
as
sal1 number ;
sal2 number ;
BEGIN
select esalary into sal1 from employee where eid=id1;
select esalary into sal2 from employee where eid=id2;
return (sal1 + sal2) / 2;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see basic syntax errors that you should avoid while creating a function.
I have tried with your data and the following works;

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION getAvg(id1 INTEGER ,id2 INTEGER) RETURNS NUMERIC(10,5) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
DECLARE sal1 NUMERIC(10,5) ;
DECLARE sal2 NUMERIC(10,5);

SELECT esalary  FROM employee WHERE eid=id1 INTO sal1 ;
SELECT esalary FROM employee WHERE eid=id2 INTO sal2 ;
RETURN (sal1 + sal2) / 2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
;
```

To check if it works, issue following query:

```
SELECT `getAvg`(1,4);
```

Comment: thanks Asgar for your quick response.

Comment: Did it work for you?